# Cannot import scipy.misc.imread

Tags: python, scipy

I've seen this problem before with other people, but haven't found a fix.

All I'm trying to do is:

`from scipy.misc import imread`

and I get

```
/home1/users/joe.borg/<ipython-input-2-f9d3d927b58f> in <module>()
----> 1 from scipy.misc import imread

/software/Python/272/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/misc/__init__.py in <module>()
     16 try:
     17     from pilutil import *
---> 18     __all__ += pilutil.__all__
     19 except ImportError:
     20     pass

NameError: name 'pilutil' is not defined
```

But it's fine when I do `from pilutil import *` on its own (no import error).  Even .../site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py exists so I've got no idea why this is failing.

Comment: Nope, I think I just used PIL and then converted it into an array in the end.

Answer (score 76):

If you have `Pillow` installed with `scipy` and it is still giving you error then check your `scipy` version because it has been removed from scipy since `1.3.0rc1`.

rather install `scipy 1.1.0` by **:**

`pip install scipy==1.1.0`

check https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6212

Comment: version `1.2.1` worked for me. Installed with `conda install -c anaconda scipy=1.2.1`

Comment: is there proper way of having script >=1.3.0 and also Pillow as well ? because my script installed wit anaconda and when I did `pip install Pillow` it shows I already have it in my anaconda path.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution has fixed my issue with the following import:

`from scipy.misc import toimage`

Answer (score 59):

You might need to install [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org).

Comment: This helped me, thanks. I installed PIL with `$sudo pip install PIL` on OS X 10.8.

Comment: I do have PIL installed, the `from pilutil import *` works fine.  Also, I can do `import PIL` and `import Image`.  Maybe it's a version problem?

Comment: On Ubuntu I had to run sudo apt-get install python-pillow

Comment: For python3: `pip3 install Pillow`

Comment: for me this worked when changed to `from scipy.misc.pilutil import imread`

Comment: for conda3 use: conda install pillow

Comment: This doesn't work for scipy versions >= v1.3.0. See my answer below.

Answer (score 31):

The method `imread` in `scipy.misc` requires the forked package of `PIL` named `Pillow`. If you are having problem installing the right version of PIL try using `imread` in other packages:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
im = imread(image.png)
```

To read  `jpg` images without `PIL` use:

```
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread(image.jpg)
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding some information, why this should work, when the import from scipy.misc fails. Short code or error dumps are flagged by the system as low-quality answers.

Answer (score 13):

looking into the documentation it says scipy.misc.imread is deprecated.
It says to install imageio, and to use imageio.imread instead. 
Works great!

Answer (score 7):

You can try 
`from scipy.misc.pilutil import imread` instead of `from scipy.misc import imread`

Please check the GitHub page : https://github.com/amueller/mglearn/issues/2
for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on user_3pij's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56684483/6126315)

If you want to work with a scipy version that is higher than 1.3.0 then, as instructed in the scipy's [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html#scipy.misc.imread) of the imread function, we can use the [imageio](https://pypi.org/project/imageio/) module instead.

To successfully use the imageio `imread` function in a way that replicates the functionality of scipy's `imread` you can follow the instructions described [here](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scipy.html) (disclaimer: I haven't tried it myself yet)

Answer (score 3):

**Scipy deprecated the image I/O functionality in v1.0 :**

> imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imread instead

Using the imageio module:

```
img = imageio.imread(fina)
```

There may be some differences. See
https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scipy.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68695867/9783962) answer.

In newer versions of `scipy`, `imread` has been removed.
You can use `imageio.imread` instead.

```
import imageio
im = imageio.imread('example.png')
```

But if you want to use scipy, you have to use version 1.0 or 1.1.
To do this, use the following command.

```
conda install -c anaconda scipy==1.0
```

Then to use "`imread`" you need to install `Pillow`.you can use below command for install `pillow` :

```
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

I received errors when trying to use

```
from scipy.misc import imread
```

I was able to remove the errors and use the above line by first installing `numpy+mkl` and then installing `scipy` from [Christoph Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

For me this was:

```
pip install numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
pip install scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

You will need to pick the correct version of the whl's for your system.

Also, make sure the `pip` command installs the modules.  If you have any 1 or more of these already installed, you might need to use pip to force a reinstall.

Comment: Do know where one can find information on which version of `Pillow` and and `scipy` are necessary for the import to work seamlessly?

Comment: @Momchill I'm not sure right now.  My advice would be to try to use conda to install pillow and scipy, check if the imports work, & look at versions conda installed.

Answer (score -1):

you have to import it like

```
from scipy import misc
```

it will work fine then.