# scipy.misc module has no attribute imread?

Tags: python, installation, scipy, dependencies, python-imaging-library

I am trying to read an image with scipy. However it does not accept the `scipy.misc.imread` part. What could be the cause of this?

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.misc
<module 'scipy.misc' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.pyc'>
>>> scipy.misc.imread('test.tif')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    scipy.misc.imread('test.tif')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imread'
```

Comment: which version of scipy are you using? `scipy.__version__` gives `0.9.0` for me and i cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: do you get the same error if you do `from scipy.misc import imread`, and then `imread('test.tif')` ?

Comment: @karthikr yes, I get the same error for that.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on scipy version `0.10.1`.

Comment: I am using scipy version 0.11.0

Comment: I think this function depends on PIL (http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) being installed. Do you have PIL?

Comment: No I don't. I will install it and give it a try.

Comment: I installed pip install scipy==1.0.0 which works

Comment: `imread` was deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and is removed in 1.2.0.
Use ``imageio.imread`` instead.

Comment: @Manas Bhardwaj, Is `imageio` a replacement for scipy's `misc`? Because, in `scipy.misc` there was `imresize` functionality, which is not there in `imageio`. Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Apparently, I found that imageio is not a replacement for the scipy.misc. Alternative for imresize of scipy.misc can be found in PIL library. [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414277/alternative-to-scipy-misc-imresize) for imresize alternative

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You need to install [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) (formerly [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)). From [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/misc.html) on `scipy.misc`:

> Note that Pillow is not a dependency of SciPy but the image manipulation functions indicated in the list below are not available without it:
>
> ...
>
> `imread`
>
> ...

After installing Pillow, I was able to access `imread` as follows:

```
In [1]: import scipy.misc

In [2]: scipy.misc.imread
Out[2]: <function scipy.misc.pilutil.imread>
```

Comment: Orz, but if I install PIL, then it will give me `<PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile...`

Comment: It should be Pillow instead of PIL now. Reference:  https://pillow.readthedocs.org/

Comment: You saved my day-but why scipy documentation is so poor! My steps are install numpy+MKL>Pillow>Scipy  all are downloaded from university of California at Irvine compiled python modules for windows.

Comment: **READ THE NEXT ANSWER** (@Shadab's answer) as well, and note that it's just `imageio`, not `scipy.imageio`.

Comment: Note that this does not work with the latest version of SciPy (1.3.0). The solution from Shadab works.

Comment: using the imageio module worked for me. Python 3.9.2 SciPy 1.6.1

Comment: Outdated answer for any recent SciPy version (>= 1.2).

Comment: i cant seem to get Pillow to work atm anyhow, no matter how i install it it says there is no module Pillow, and which pillow: `pillow not found` despite it also saying when i try to reinstall: `Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (8.3.1)`. so maybe thats a non standard path problem or a brew problem, but im not sure how to fix it. and the `imageio` solution just works. ive had Pillow installed and functional before in the past, so not sure whatsup.

Answer (score 173):

`imread` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
Use [`imageio.imread`](http://imageio.github.io) instead.

```
import imageio
im = imageio.imread('astronaut.png')
im.shape  # im is a numpy array
(512, 512, 3)
imageio.imwrite('imageio:astronaut-gray.jpg', im[:, :, 0])
```

Comment: SciPy's imread used to return a numpy.ndarray. imageio.imread returns imageio.core.util.Array. If you want/need a numpy.ndarray and don't want to convert it, use matplotlib.pyplot.imread, as it also returns a numpy.ndarray.

Comment: I have a similar problem here, but with respect to `imresize`. Previously, `scipy.misc.imresize` works. Now it is deprecated and where will I get an alternative for this?

Comment: It's a joke @saichand

Comment: @filip, I tried using the scipy.misc.imresize. It doesn't work now, but I had used it sometime back.
I wish You could correct me if what I said had any mistakes in that comment rather than saying it as a joke. I am open to learning from my mistakes. What is wrong in my comment? Thank you.

Comment: Well I have to admit it I was a little bit frustrated with my comment at that time I wrote it :P. I meant that it's a joke they didn't provide wheels or installations below 1.0 for scipy on windows. If you're still looking to use it just use scipy==1.2.0 since it's still available there (just marked as deprecated, still works!) @saichand

Comment: Does the `imageio.core.util.Array` have the correct dtype?  Does a 8 bit image get returned at `uint8`?

Comment: When writing your own code, use the newer alternatives. But when trying to run some code you know little about, it's easier to install an old scipy version, e.g. in conda `conda install scipy==1.2.1`. There seems to be no drop-in replacement for both imread and imresize.

Comment: @Stefan There is virtually no difference between a `imageio.core.util.Array` (it is - in fact - a ndarray subclass) and `np.ndarray` except for the additional `_meta` field. If you don't need metadata, you can simply call `np.asarray(iio.imread(...))` to discard it; the "conversion" will be very efficient since there is nothing to convert. Also note that mpl forwards everything to pillow internally, whereas imageio may use additional backends if pillow support for a format isn't great (TIFF) or absent (raw formats, video, ...).

Answer (score 62):

imread is depreciated after version 1.2.0!
So to solve this issue I had to install version 1.1.0.

```
pip install scipy==1.1.0
```

Comment: See @Shadab's answer, it's in `imageio` now.

Comment: It is removed starting 1.3.0, so the latest to install is at least 1.2.1

Comment: Removing and installing an older version is not a solution.

Answer (score 43):

For Python 3, it is best to use `imread` in `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
```

Comment: No, its not.  MatPlotlib converts to `float`.

`cv2.imread()` correctly preserves the dtype of the image.

Answer (score 19):

In case anyone encountering the same issue, please uninstall scipy and install scipy==1.1.0

```
$ pip uninstall scipy

$ pip install scipy==1.1.0
```

Comment: as @Pieter Meiresone removing and installing an older version is not a solution.It is may be conflict with other package that have dependency on scipy.

Answer (score 11):

As answered misc.imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
imageio is one option,it will return object of type :

```
<class 'imageio.core.util.Image'>
```

but instead of imageio, use cv2

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('astronaut.png')
```

im will be of type :
`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

As numpy arrays are faster to compute.

Comment: imageio works, but cv2 cause error : libpng warning: Invalid image height in IHDR

Answer (score 9):

You need the Python Imaging Library (PIL) but alas! the PIL project seems to have been abandoned. In particular, it hasn't been ported to Python 3. So if you want PIL functionality in Python 3, you'll do well do use [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/), which is the semi-official fork of PIL and appears to be actively developed. Actually, if you need a modern PIL implementation at all I'd recommend Pillow. It's as simple as `pip install pillow`. As it uses the same namespace as PIL it's essentially a drop-in replacement.

*How "semi-official" is this fork?* you may ask. The [About](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/about.html) page of the Pillow docs say this:

> As more time passes since the last PIL release, the likelihood of a
>   new PIL release decreases. However, we’ve yet to hear an official “PIL
>   is dead” announcement. So if you still want to support PIL, please
>   report issues here first, then open corresponding Pillow tickets here.
>
> Please provide a link to the first ticket so we can track the issue(s)
>   upstream.

However, the most recent PIL release on the [official PIL site](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is dated November 15, 2009. I think we can safely proclaim Pillow as the successor of PIL after (as of this writing) nearly eight years of no new releases. So even if you don't need Python 3 support, I suggest you eschew the ancient PIL 1.1.6 distribution available in PyPI and just install fresh, up-to-date, compatible Pillow.

Answer (score 9):

Install the Pillow library by following commands:

```
pip install pillow
```

Note, the selected answer has been outdated. See the docs of 
 [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/misc.html)

> Note that Pillow (https://python-pillow.org/) is not a dependency of SciPy, but the image manipulation functions indicated in the list below are not available without it.

Answer (score 4):

Imread uses PIL library, if the library is installed use :

```
from scipy.ndimage import imread
```

Source: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html

Comment: this works for me ! though I don't understand why my professor use "from scipy.misc import imread" and it doesn't work on my laptop

Answer (score 3):

```
python -m pip install pillow
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need a python image library ([**PIL**](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)), but now PIL only is not enough, you'd better install [**Pillow**](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). This works well.

Comment: There's a comment on the accepted answer already stating that `pillow` should be used instead of `PIL`. I don't think it's a bad idea to add it as an answer, but it would be by far more useful if you explained why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following in a Jupyter Notebook, I had a similar error message:

```
from skimage import data
photo_data = misc.imread('C:/Users/ers.jpg')
type(photo_data)
```

'error' msg:

> D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3:
>   DeprecationWarning: `imread` is deprecated! `imread` is deprecated in
>   SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use `imageio.imread`
>   instead.   This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid
>   doing imports until

And using the following I got it solved:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
photo_data = matplotlib.pyplot.imread('C:/Users/ers.jpg')
type(photo_data)
```

Comment: It doesn't related to the question. It is a different problem and answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have all the packages required for the image extraction on jupyter notebook, but even then it shows me the same error.

[Error on Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeNSn.png)

Reading the above comments, I have installed the required packages. Please do tell if I have missed some packages.

```
pip3 freeze | grep -i -E "pillow|scipy|scikit-image"
Pillow==5.4.1
scikit-image==0.14.2

scipy==1.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that work for me in python 3.6 is the following

> py -m pip install Pillow

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get the `.png` file I'm working with in as `uint8` was with OpenCv.

`cv2.imread(file)` actually returned `numpy.ndarray` with `dtype=uint8`

Answer (score 0):

You must first install the Python version compatible with scipy (<3.7).
I could not use pip to install scipy version 1.0 [ I think this version is no longer supported on pip] and used conda instead:

```
conda install -c anaconda scipy==1.0
```

Then to use "imread" you need to install Pillow.

```
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

imread is deprecated in scipy.misc; use imageio.imread instead.

imageio provides the same functionality as Scipy. But keep in mind that some arguments need to be changed (for detailed information please check [here](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scipy.html?highlight=imread)):

1. Instead of `mode`, use the `pilmode` keyword argument.
2. Instead of `flatten`, use the `as_gray` keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use PIL like this:

```
    from PIL import Image
    input_image = Image.open(filename)
```