# No image functions in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

Tried to use `scipy.misc.imread`but got an error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imread'`.

I know that I have to install `PIL` to use image functions as [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345790/module-has-no-attribute-imread) suggests. However, I got it installed but no help.

I have `scipy` installed via `ScipySuperpack`. `PIL` installed via `pip`. Using OS X machine.

Comment: Look for the file `scipy/misc/pilutil.py`. If it is not there, I am guessing you have to install PIL first, then (re)install scipy.

Comment: Actually `pilutil.py` is there...

Comment: In an interactive shell, if you `import scipy.misc`, then look at `scipy.misc.__file__`, does it show the a path to the same directory as  the one containing `pilutil.py`? If so, open `__init__.py` in the same directory and look for any mention of `pilutil`. Perhaps post what you see here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the module:

```
import scipy.ndimage
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the scipy extension scikit-image, which offers an abundance of image related operations:
http://scikit-image.org/