# Reading an image in python - experimenting with images

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy, imread

I'm experimenting a little bit working with images in Python for a project I'm working on.

This is the first time ever for me programming in Python and I haven't found a tutorial that deals with the issues I'm facing.

I'm experimenting with different image decompositions, and I want to define some variable `A` as a set image from a specified folder. Basically I'm looking for Python's analog of Matlab's `imread`.

After googling for a bit, I found many solutions but none seem to work for me for some reason.

For example even this simple code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
```

which is supposed to work (taken from http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) yields the error "No module named cv2".

Why does this happen? How can I read an image?

Another thing I tried is

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.io as io
A=io.imread('C:\Users\Oria\Desktop\test.jpg')
io.imshow(A)
```

which yields the error "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"

All I want to do is be able to read an image from a specified folder, shouldn't be hard...Should also be noted that the database I work with is ppm files. So I want to read and show ppm images.

Edit: My enviornment is Pyzo. If it matters for anything.

Edit2: Changing the back slashes into forward slashes changes the error to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 1>", line 3, in <module>
    A=io.imread('C:/Users/Oria/Desktop/test.jpg')
  File "F:\pyzo2015a\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 97, in imread
    img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
  File "F:\pyzo2015a\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 209, in call_plugin
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\pyzo2015a\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2215, in imread
    return _imread(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\pyzo2015a\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1258, in imread
    'more images' % list(six.iterkeys(handlers.keys)))
  File "F:\pyzo2015a\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 552, in iterkeys
    return iter(d.keys(**kw))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: `cv2` isn't something that comes with Python, you have to install it. If the import doesn't work, you've installed it incorrectly. The Unicode error sounds like you have some non-ascii characters in the filename, but without the full error stack it's hard to tell.

Comment: The entire error stack is   File "<tmp 1>", line 3
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Change the backward slashes \ in your Windows path to forward slashes /.

Comment: Tried it now. Please see the edit I made for the result

Comment: @MattDMo good catch, I totally missed that. Could have doubled up on the backslashes to `\\` too. No idea what the new error is about.

Comment: I don't understand how can it be so difficult to do the simplest things...

Answer (score 1):

The closest analogue to Matlab's imread is [scipy.misc.imread](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html), part of the [scipy](http://scipy.org/) package. I would write this code as:

```
import scipy.misc
image_array = scipy.misc.imread('filename.jpg')
```

Now to your broader questions. The reason this seems hard is because you're coming from Matlab, which uses a different philosophy. Matlab is a monolithic install that comes out of the box with a huge number of functions. Python is modular. The built-in library is relatively small, and then you install packages depending on what you want to do. For instance, the packages `scipy` (scientific computing), `cv2` (computer vision), and `PIL` (image processing) can all read simple images from disk, so you choose between them depending on what else from the package you might want to use.

This provides a lot more flexibility, but it does require you to become comfortable installing packages. Sadly this is much more difficult on Windows than on Linux-like systems, due to the lack of a "package manager". On Linux I can `sudo apt-get install scipy` and install all of scipy in one line. In Windows, you might be better off installing something like [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) that smooths the package installation process.

Comment: That does not seem to work. I can do import scipy.misc, meaning i already have that package installed, but Pyzo won't let me do scipy.misc.imread. It yields the error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 1>", line 2, in <module>
    image_array = scipy.misc.imread('filename.jpg')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imread'"

Comment: You might need to install PIL too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345790/module-has-no-attribute-imread