# Successfully installed SciPy, but "from scipy.misc import imread" gives ImportError: cannot import name 'imread'

Tags: tensorflow, scipy, ubuntu-16.04, python-import

I have successfully installed scipy, numpy, and pillow, however I get error as below

> ImportError: cannot import name 'imread'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy.misc module has no attribute imread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30720760/5615276)

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the same steps?

```
import scipy.misc
img = scipy.misc.imread('my_image_path')

# To verify image is read properly.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`imread` and `imsave` are deprecated in scipy.misc

Use `imageio.imread` instead after `import imageio`.

For saving -
Use `imageio.imsave` instead or use `imageio.write`

For resizing use `skimage.transform.resize` instead after `import skimage`