# Storing output of URL directly into numpy raster

Tags: python, numpy, python-requests, rasterio

Is there a way to store the output of a url that returns a geotiff (or tiff file) directly into a numpy array or rasterio variable using the python requests library (or any other python library)? I can use python requests for a json like this:

```
requests.get(URL).json()
```

Comment: [`Maybe with scipy.misc.imread`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44058783/3293881)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
requests.get(URL).content
```

gives you the binary data from your file which you may be able to convert using the `numpy.frombuffer` function. But if I remember correctly, the geotiff format has some header information which you would have to offset for.

Alternatively, you could save the file to disc

```
open('myfile.tiff','wb').write(requests.get(URL).content)
```

and then read it using something like the `scipy.ndimage.imread` function.