# Importing image to python :cannot import name 'imread'

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I want to import an image.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave, imresize
# Read an JPEG image into a numpy array
img = imread('Cover.jpg')
print(img.dtype, img.shape)
```

but I face with following error: `cannot import name 'imread'`
I've already successfully installed numpy and scipy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy.misc module has no attribute imread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345790/scipy-misc-module-has-no-attribute-imread)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You also need to install PIL (Pillow) as that is what `scipy` uses to read images:

```
pip install Pillow
```

note [from the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html):

> imread uses the Python Imaging Library (PIL) to read an image. The following notes are from the PIL documentation.

however, you might want to think about switching to `scipy.imageio.imread` since `scipy.misc.imread` is [deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) :

> imread is deprecated! imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imread instead

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
from imageio import imread
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently a lot of people had this issue and the solution was to install `Pillow`. Perhaps try to install Pillow and run it again

```
sudo pip install Pillow==2.6.0
```

Source of information: https://github.com/Newmu/stylize/issues/1

Comment: It's not a "workaround" since it is not a bug, it is expected behaviour, since scipy need PIL(Pillow) to be able to read images. It even says in the docs

Answer (score 4):

First, you should have Pillow, later your scipy version should be lower than 1.1.0

```
pip install Pillow
pip install scipy==1.1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Install pillow

```
    pip3 install pillow
```

As scipy.misc is deprecated you cannot use it but instead

```
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    im = Image.open('hopper.jpg')
    a = np.asarray(im)
    im = Image.fromarray(a)
```

this returns an image object

Answer (score 3):

Note: Posting the already given advises with a bit more as my reputation does not allow to comment

In the latest version of scipy (1.3.0) functions like imread, imsave, imresize is deprecated.
Downgrading scipy from 1.3.0 to 1.1.0 works like a charm and you will be able to use not just imread but all the above-mentioned functions which are almost necessary in most situations

The command for downgrading:

```
pip install scipy==1.1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

From me this worked "from scipy.misc import imsave", when installed 1.2.1 version of scipy.

```
pip install scipy==1.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Install PIL - Python imaging library.
pip install Pillow

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your version of scipy does not contain imread (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html)

Than use imageio.imread instead (see as well comments here on some changes in parameters names https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scipy.html)

Answer (score -1):

This works in the latest version...

```
from scipy.ndimage import imread
```

Answer (score -1):

**This will work in latest version of scipy**

```
from scipy.misc.pilutil import imread
```

Answer (score -2):

Change to imageio will fix the problem

`imread is deprecated! imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imread instead`