# regarding AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imread'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I was trying some code segment,

```
from scipy import misc
im = misc.imread(file_image, True)
```

However, I got the error message such as

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imread'
```

What can be the reason of this?

Comment: Do you have Pillow installed also? The image stuff isn't available without it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy.misc module has no attribute imread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345790/scipy-misc-module-has-no-attribute-imread)

Answer (score 6):

This is because imread was discontinued by scipy as of 1.2.0, to solve it you can either install Pillow with

```
    pip install Pillow
```

or downgrade to 1.1.0 with

```
    pip install scipy==1.1.0
```