# AttributeError while running Scipy.ndimages.imread

Tags: python, scipy, pip, python-module

when running:

```py
import scipy
scipy.ndimage.imread('path/to/image',mode='RGB')
```

I got

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy.ndimage' has no attribute 'imread'
```

I already tried to uninstall and reinstall scipy and also to reinstall Pillow and numpy as said [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345790/scipy-misc-module-has-no-attribute-imread)

Is there some missing module?

Comment: imread is deprecated and removed since 1.2. Which version of scipy are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy.misc module has no attribute imread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345790/scipy-misc-module-has-no-attribute-imread)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue today as well. This happens because scipy.ndimage.imread is deprecated, see doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html#scipy.ndimage.imread).

To do the same, you can to use the imageio package

```
conda install -c conda-forge imageio
```

After this, you can do

```
import imageio
imageio.imread('path/to/image',mode='RGB')
```

Answer (score 0):

A library that provides `imread` which most people already have is `matplotlib`. Just use it like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.pyplot.imread('path')
```

Comment: MatPlotlib is converting the image to `float`!

Answer (score 0):

Using pytorch below method worked for me.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imread('Image_path')