# How to resize an image now that scipy.misc.imresize has been removed from scipy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I want to use an old script which uses `scipy.misc.imresize`.
But unfortunately it is removed entirely from scipy. 
I do not understand what it does so what code will perform the same action as the above line.

I tried using `skimage.transform.resize(image, (num_px*num_px*3, 1), order = 3)`
But get the error - `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12288 into shape (1200,1)`

Edit: More Information

It's classifying pictures as belonging to one of two sets.

```
my_image = "anyimage.jpg" #any image form the internet

#Preprocessing the image
fname = "images/" + my_image
image = np.array(ndimage.imread(fname, flatten=False))
image = image/255.
my_image = scipy.misc.imresize(image, size=(num_px,num_px)).reshape((1, num_px*num_px*3)).T #The original code which worked perfectly

my_predicted_image = predict(d["w"], d["b"], my_image) #predict function uses 
#linear regression where the third parameter must be data of 
#size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to scipy.misc.imresize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414277/alternative-to-scipy-misc-imresize)

Comment: No. I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: Please provide more details (ideally an [mcve]) and someone might be able to help you. Right now, we're just guessing based on a partial error message and no data.

Comment: Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `scipy` image routines `imread()` and `imresize()` which have been deprecated and removed, you can do the same thing using `pillow`, which you should already have since it is required for the `scipy` functions to work.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

my_image = "anyimage.jpg" #any image form the internet
fname = "images/" + my_image

num_px = 20  # a guess based on the shape of (1200, 1) in your error message

#Preprocessing the image
image = Image.open(fname).resize(size=(num_px, num_px))  # use PIL to open and reshape image
my_image = np.array(image, dtype=float) / 255  # convert to numpy array and scale values
my_image = my_image.reshape((1, num_px*num_px*3)).T  # reshape and transpose

my_predicted_image = predict(d["w"], d["b"], my_image) #predict function uses 
#linear regression where the third parameter must be data of 
#size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

my_image = "anyimage.jpg" #any image form the internet
fname = "images/" + my_image

#Preprocessing the image
image = Image.open(fname).resize(size=(num_px, num_px))  # use PIL to open and reshape image
my_image = np.array(image, dtype=float) / 255  # convert to numpy array and scale values
my_image = my_image.reshape((1, num_px*num_px*3)).T  # reshape and transpose

my_predicted_image = predict(d["w"], d["b"], my_image)
```

Comment: Just remove num_px = 20 from the above solution