# How to read a maze from an image and convert it to binary values in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, maze

I want some way (In Python 3) to read pixels of a maze image and the expected output should be a binary list [[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]] (1 for white and 0 for black for example) (should look something like this, the values are for the sake of the example) I don't want a method to solve the maze, all I need is something that enable an internal representation of the maze given an image. I want to be able to make whatever the algorithm of choice to be able to draw its execution and show path and maybe show progression as well. (I don't want an algorithm, I just want a way of reading a maze image and writing new maze images to show the chosen path/ show progression of the algorithm regardless of what the algorithm is (Dijkstra, A*, Breadth-first search ...)

I tried using PIL and cv2 but as I'm not an expert on the subject, I don't know what I should do

Here's are some example mazes:

Small maze:

[image]

Big maze:

[image]

Comment: see [Convert a simple mono drawing image to a 2d text array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63194022/2521214)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load a PNG, GIF, TIF or JPEG file like this, then ensure it only has `0` and `1` values and process the pixels with PIL/Pillow and Numpy.

I used this edited version of your mini-maze:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open the maze image and make greyscale, and get its dimensions
im = Image.open('maze.png').convert('L')
w, h = im.size

# Ensure all black pixels are 0 and all white pixels are 1
binary = im.point(lambda p: p > 128 and 1)

# Resize to half its height and width so we can fit on Stack Overflow, get new dimensions
binary = binary.resize((w//2,h//2),Image.NEAREST)
w, h = binary.size

# Convert to Numpy array - because that's how images are best stored and processed in Python
nim = np.array(binary)

# Print that puppy out 
for r in range(h):
    for c in range(w):
        print(nim[r,c],end='')
    print()
```

Here's the result:

```
000000000000000000001111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111100
001111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
000000000000000000001111111111111111110011111111111111111110000000000000000000111111111111111111100
000000000000000000001111111111111111110011111111111111111100000000000000000000011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111110111111111000000000001000000000000001100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111100111111111111111111111111111111111111100111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
001111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111111111100
000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Can you please tell us how to do it with any image (color or black/white). I want your the result to be as as your result. Please help in this!

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal Questions are free! If you have different requirements, say with colours or something else, just ask a new one. You can click `share` just 2cm above this comment and get a link to copy, then paste the link into your new question to link them up then add in whatever is different - and show your own attempt at solving it.

Comment: `# Ensure all black pixels are 0 and all white pixels are 1
binary = im.point(lambda p: p > 128 and 1)`
In above code what "128" and "1" signifies ?

Comment: Can we do this for pdf also?

Comment: You can convert a PDF to PNG with **ImageMagick** using `convert input.pdf output.png` Or you can install **Poppler tools** and use the program `pdfimages` in there to extract the PNG out of the PDF.

Comment: Can't we do this directly without having to convert it to the image?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import imread

im = imread("maze.jpg") # values from 0 to 255
im = im.astype(np.float) / 255. # 0 to 1
im[im>0.5] = 1.0 # round
im[im<=0.5] = 0.0

x = np.linspace(0, 1, im.shape[0])
y = np.linspace(0, 1, im.shape[1])

plt.contourf(x, y, im)
plt.colorbar()
```

Here's a test image I used:
[image]

Comment: @ Artur from scipy.ndimage import imread
ImportError: cannot import name 'imread' from 'scipy.ndimage'

Comment: Which version of scipy do you use? I have 0.18.1 (hint: import scipy; scipy.__version__).

Comment: scipy version: 1.3.1

Comment: Hmm, maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345790/scipy-misc-module-has-no-attribute-imread. They say that in newer scipy you should use this instead: imageio.imread

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to perform this tasks on jpeg, you can try with simpler format.

You can, for exemple, begin with **PGM files**.

PGM are grayscale image (black and white image). You can create a very simple PGM file using gimp (Export As -> PGM -> raw).

For the example, I drawed this really simple 4*4 image:

[image: maze]

*Be careful ! The image I just linked is a jpeg big sized version of my 4*4 pgm image ! It's not my real file !*

PGM, like all kind of image, is a format that **follows a norm**

You can find the norm [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/pgm.5.html)

The **most interesting part** is here:

> Each PGM image consists of the following:
>
> A "magic number" for identifying the file type.  A pgm image's magic number is  the  two characters "P5".
>
> Whitespace (blanks, TABs, CRs, LFs).
>
> A width, formatted as ASCII characters in decimal.
>
> Whitespace.
>
> ...

It describes how a PGM file is formatted !

So now, according to this norm, we can create a **very simple python PGM parser !**

```py
# Opening my PGM file. Since this is a raw encoded file, img.read() will read
# bytes !
img = open('./maze_test.pgm', 'rb')

# This line means this is a PGM file. 
# It is encoded in ASCII. So, since every ASCII character is encoded with 1 byte,
# we have to read 2 bytes according to the norm
print(img.read(2))

# This is a blank line
print(img.readline())

# This line is a GIMP comment
print(img.readline())

# This line is an ASCII line. It contains the width, encoded in ASCII, then a 
# space, and then the height also encoded in ASCII
width_height = str(img.readline())
# Remove the python byte information
width_height = width_height[2:-3]

# We split this line in an list
width_height = width_height.split(' ')

# The first element represents the width
width = int(width_height[0])
# The second represents the height
height = int(width_height[1])

# The max_value encoded in ASCII
max_value = int(img.readline())

# Now, there is only byte data

pixel_map = []
for row in range(width):
    # We prepare the next line in our list
    pixel_map.append([])
    for column in range(height):
        # The value that we read is a byte. We simply use ord to convert it to int
        pixel_value = ord(img.read(1))

        # We normalize the value using the max_value
        pixel_value = pixel_value//max_value

        pixel_map[row].append(pixel_value)

# Here is the pixel map
print(pixel_map)
```

Outputs:
`[[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]`

Comment: @ wakobu your code does not work, it produces an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/mz.py", line 26, in <module>
    width = int(width_height[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\x00\\x00\\x00\\rIHDR\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xf2\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xa2\\x08\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00{\\xe6\\x90S\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01sRGB\\x00\\xae\\xce\\x1c\\xe9\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x04gAMA\\x00\\x00\\xb1\\x8f\\x0b\\

Comment: Are you sure that you created a PGM raw file ? It looks like there is RGB channel...
Your image has to be a PGM file, not Jpeg or any other format.
In GIMP, draw your black and white PGM image, then File -> Export As -> [Name of you image].pgm -> Raw

Comment: Also, note than in my code, I wrote this: ```python # This line is a GIMP comment print(img.readline())``` If you don't have any comments or if you have more than one in your image, this line will break the program

Comment: @ wakobu i forgot about the gimp conversion, i'll try converting the file and run it again