# Convert a simple mono drawing image to a 2d text array

Tags: algorithm, text, data-structures, maze

I am trying to develop an algorithm that converts simple mono line images ie Maze, to a text 2d array.

For example, the image below, it would be converted to the following text array.

[image]

```
[|------------         |]
[|     |               |]
[|                     |]
[|  |------|      ---- |]
[|         |      |    |]
[|         |     ---   |] 
[|---      |        |  |]
[|         |---     |  |] 
[|     |      |        |]
[|    ---------------  |]
[|                     |]
[|  -------------------|]
```

and finally, like this, where 0=obstacle and 1=free passage

```
[0000000000000111111110]
[0111110111111111111110]
[0111111111111111111110]
[0110000000011111100000]
[0111111111011111011110]
[0111111111011111000110] 
[0000111111011111111010]
[0111111111000011111010] 
[0111110111111011111110]
[0111100000000000000010]
[0111111111111111111110]
[0110000000000000000000]
```

I am thinking to use an Image to Line Art Text like algorithms, ie
https://www.text-image.com/convert/pic2ascii.cgi

What do you think about this approach?

Comment: The array doesn't look like the image to me...  
Try "box drawing" ascii characters, see: https://theasciicode.com.ar/ - to "type" character, hold Alt-key and on keypad enter code.  Alt-Key and 42 will produce "*"...

Comment: @iAmOren yes the final array is an approximation of 0 and 1 that I made it by hand. I am interested in an algorithm on how to achieve this automatically.

Comment: I understand, but your 3rd row shows a clear line which is not so in the image.

Comment: A "better" representation (in javascript): `var maze=[
  "xxxxxxxxxxx x",
  "x   x       x",
  "x x x x xxxxx",
  "x x   x x   x",
  "x xxxxx xxx x",
  "x     x   x x",
  "xxx x xxx x x",
  "x   x   x   x",
  "x xxxxxxxxx x",
  "x           x",
  "x xxxxxxxxxxx"
];`  
Here, my "x"s are your "0"s and my " "s (spaces) are your "1"s.

Comment: How are you "reading" the image?

Comment: Use "+"s for intersections - this should clear up some obstacles.

Comment: I have access to the real data (pixels) of the uncompressed image

Comment: I see you want to use double space to make it more square-like...

Comment: can you give an example of how you access the real data (pixels) of the uncompressed image?

Comment: @iAmOren {rgb(0,0,0), rgb(255.36.27), rgb(0,0,0)...…} where the 1st element of the array is the left top pixel of the image.

Comment: Then just map that array: rgb(0,0,0) -> "+", and anything else -> " " (blank)...  
You could sample to see distances from lines, and look for rgb(0,0,0) in the neighborhood...

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57614336/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes it seems a very similar project. The only problem here is to optimize the image since in my case it is a scanned image, and the black / white pixels doesn't have absolute values. Thanks

Comment: @Maverick very interseting problem... I want to give it a try in C++/VCL but it will take me a while (and not sure if I can finish today)... right now I have some preprocessing + H,V line vectorization and partial grid computation ... so just 2x GCD and conversion from vector grid aligned lines to text  character +/- some tweaking... will add an answer when finished... meanwhile take a look at this: [Image to ASCII art conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32987834/2521214)  for some additional ideas ...

Comment: @Spektre Excellent source thanks, I already tried some examples under Python as Mark Setchell recommended above. The final project will be implemented in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interseting problem its basically vector form of [Image to ASCII art conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32987834/2521214)... I managed to do this with this algorithm:

1. **preprocess image**

   You gave us JPG which has lossy compresion meaning your image contain much more than just 2 colors. So there are shades and artifacts which will screw things up. So first we must get rid of those by thresholding and recoloring. So we can have 2D BW image (no grayscales)
2. **vectorize**

   Your maze is axis aligned so it contains only horizontal and vertical (`h`,`v`) lines. So simply scan each line of image find first starting wall pixel then its ending pixel and store somewhere... repeat until whole line is processed and do this for all lines. Again do the same for rows of image. As your image has thick walls ignore lines sorter than thickness threshold and remove adjacent (duplicates) line that are (almost) the same.
3. **get list of possible grid coordinates from h,v lines**

   simply make a list of all x and y (separately) coordinates from lines start and end points. Then sort them and remove too close coordinates (duplicates).

   Now the min and max values gives you AABB of your maze and GCD of all the `coordinate-lowest coordinate` will give you grid size.
4. **align h,v lines to grid**

   simply round all start/end points to nearest grid position ...
5. **create text buffer for maze**

   AABB along with grid size will give you resolution of your maz in cells so simply create 2D text buffer where each cell has `NxN` characters. I am using `6x3` cells which looks nice enough (square and with enough space inside).
6. **renmder h,v lines into text**

   simply loop through all lines and render `-` or `|` instead of pixels... I am using also `+` if the target position does not contain ' '.
7. **convert 2D text array into wanted text output**

   simply copy the lines into single text ... or if you clever enough you can have 1D and 2D at the same memory place with `eol` encoded between lines.

**Here simple example in C++/VCL I made from the exampe in the link above:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <jpeg.hpp>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "win_main.h"
#include "List.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
int txt_xs=0,txt_ys=0,txt_xf=0;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> void sort_asc_bubble(T *a,int n)
    {
    int i,e; T a0,a1;
    for (e=1;e;n--)                                     // loop until no swap occurs
     for (e=0,a0=a[0],a1=a[1],i=1;i<n;a0=a1,i++,a1=a[i])// proces unsorted part of array
      if (a0>a1)                                        // condition if swap needed
      { a[i-1]=a1; a[i]=a0; a1=a0; e=1; }               // swap and allow to process array again
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnsiString bmp2lintxt(Graphics::TBitmap *bmp)
    {
    bool debug=false;
    const int cx=6;             // cell size
    const int cy=3;
    const int thr_bw=400;       // BW threshold
    const int thr_thickness=10; // wall thikness threshold
    char a;
    AnsiString txt="",eol="\r\n";
    int x,y,x0,y0,x1,y1,xs,ys,gx,gy,nx,ny,i,i0,i1,j;
    union { BYTE db[4]; DWORD dd; } c; DWORD **pyx;
    List<int> h,v;  // horizontal and vertical lines (x,y,size)
    List<int> tx,ty;// temp lists for grid GCD computation
    // [init stuff]
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    xs=bmp->Width ;
    ys=bmp->Height;
    if (xs<=0) return txt;
    if (ys<=0) return txt;
    pyx=new DWORD*[ys];
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++) pyx[y]=(DWORD*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
    i=xs; if (i<ys) i=ys;
    // threshold bmp to B&W
    x0=xs; x1=0; y0=xs; y1=0;
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++)
     for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
        {
        c.dd=pyx[y][x];
        i =c.db[0];
        i+=c.db[1];
        i+=c.db[2];
        if (i>=thr_bw) c.dd=0x00FFFFFF;
        else           c.dd=0x00000000;
        pyx[y][x]=c.dd;
        }
    if (debug) bmp->SaveToFile("out0_bw.bmp");
    // [vectorize]
    // get horizontal lines
    i0=0; i1=0; h.num=0;
    for (y0=0;y0<ys;y0++)
        {
        for (x0=0;x0<xs;)
            {
            for (     ;x0<xs;x0++) if (!pyx[y0][x0]) break;
            for (x1=x0;x1<xs;x1++) if ( pyx[y0][x1]){ x1--; break; }
            i=x1-x0;
            if (i>thr_thickness)
                {
                h.add(x0);
                h.add(y0);
                h.add(i);
                }
            x0=x1+1;
            }
        // remove duplicate lines
        for (i=i0;i<i1;i+=3)
         for (j=i1;j<h.num;j+=3)
          if ((abs(h[i+0]-h[j+0])<thr_thickness)&&(abs(h[i+2]-h[j+2])<thr_thickness))
            {
            h.del(i);
            h.del(i);
            h.del(i);
            i1-=3; i-=3; break;
            }
        i0=i1; i1=h.num;
        }
    // get vertical lines
    i0=0; i1=0; v.num=0;
    for (x0=0;x0<xs;x0++)
        {
        for (y0=0;y0<ys;)
            {
            for (     ;y0<ys;y0++) if (!pyx[y0][x0]) break;
            for (y1=y0;y1<ys;y1++) if ( pyx[y1][x0]){ y1--; break; }
            i=y1-y0;
            if (i>thr_thickness)
                {
                v.add(x0);
                v.add(y0);
                v.add(i);
                }
            y0=y1+1;
            }
        // remove duplicate lines
        for (i=i0;i<i1;i+=3)
         for (j=i1;j<v.num;j+=3)
          if ((abs(v[i+1]-v[j+1])<thr_thickness)&&(abs(v[i+2]-v[j+2])<thr_thickness))
            {
            v.del(i);
            v.del(i);
            v.del(i);
            i1-=3; i-=3; break;
            }
        i0=i1; i1=v.num;
        }
    // [compute grid]
    x0=xs; y0=ys; x1=0; y1=0;   // AABB
    gx=10; gy=10;               // grid cell size
    nx=0; ny=0;                 // grid cells
    tx.num=0; ty.num=0;         // clear possible x,y coordinates
    for (i=0;i<h.num;i+=3)
        {
        x =h[i+0];
        y =h[i+1];
        if (x0>x) x0=x; if (x1<x) x1=x; for (j=0;j<tx.num;j++) if (tx[j]==x){ j=-1; break; } if (j>=0) tx.add(x);
        if (y0>y) y0=y; if (y1<y) y1=y; for (j=0;j<ty.num;j++) if (ty[j]==y){ j=-1; break; } if (j>=0) ty.add(y);
        x+=h[i+2];
        if (x0>x) x0=x; if (x1<x) x1=x; for (j=0;j<tx.num;j++) if (tx[j]==x){ j=-1; break; } if (j>=0) tx.add(x);
        }
    for (i=0;i<v.num;i+=3)
        {
        x =v[i+0];
        y =v[i+1];
        if (x0>x) x0=x; if (x1<x) x1=x; for (j=0;j<tx.num;j++) if (tx[j]==x){ j=-1; break; } if (j>=0) tx.add(x);
        if (y0>y) y0=y; if (y1<y) y1=y; for (j=0;j<ty.num;j++) if (ty[j]==y){ j=-1; break; } if (j>=0) ty.add(y);
        y+=v[i+2];
        if (y0>y) y0=y; if (y1<y) y1=y; for (j=0;j<ty.num;j++) if (ty[j]==y){ j=-1; break; } if (j>=0) ty.add(y);
        }
    // order tx,ty
    sort_asc_bubble(tx.dat,tx.num);
    sort_asc_bubble(ty.dat,ty.num);
    // remove too close coordinates
    for (i=1;i<tx.num;i++) if (tx[i]-tx[i-1]<=thr_thickness){ tx.del(i); i--; }
    for (i=1;i<ty.num;i++) if (ty[i]-ty[i-1]<=thr_thickness){ ty.del(i); i--; }
    // estimate gx,gy
    for (gx=x1-x0,i=1;i<tx.num;i++){ x=tx[i]-tx[i-1]; if (gx>x) gx=x; } nx=(x1-x0+1)/gx; gx=(x1-x0+1)/nx; x1=x0+nx*gx;
    for (gy=y1-y0,i=1;i<ty.num;i++){ y=ty[i]-ty[i-1]; if (gy>y) gy=y; } ny=(y1-y0+1)/gy; gy=(y1-y0+1)/ny; y1=y0+ny*gy;
    // align x,y to grid: multiplicate nx,ny by cx,cy to form boxes and enlarge by 1 for final border lines
    nx=(cx*nx)+1;
    ny=(cy*ny)+1;
    // align h,v lines to grid
    for (i=0;i<h.num;i+=3)
        {
        x=h[i+0]-x0; x=((x+(gx>>1))/gx)*gx; h[i+0]=x+x0;
        y=h[i+1]-y0; y=((y+(gy>>1))/gy)*gy; h[i+1]=y+y0;
        j=h[i+2];    j=((j+(gx>>1))/gx)*gx; h[i+2]=j;
        }
    for (i=0;i<v.num;i+=3)
        {
        x=v[i+0]-x0; x=((x+(gx>>1))/gx)*gx; v[i+0]=x+x0;
        y=v[i+1]-y0; y=((y+(gy>>1))/gy)*gy; v[i+1]=y+y0;
        j=v[i+2];    j=((j+(gy>>1))/gy)*gy; v[i+2]=j;
        }
    // [h,v lines -> ASCII Art]
    char *text=new char[nx*ny];
    char **tyx=new char*[ny];
    for (y=0;y<ny;y++)
     for (tyx[y]=text+(nx*y),x=0;x<nx;x++)
      tyx[y][x]=' ';
    // h lines
    for (i=0;i<h.num;i+=3)
        {
        x=(h[i+0]-x0)/gx;
        y=(h[i+1]-y0)/gy;
        j=(h[i+2]   )/gx; j+=x;
        x*=cx; y*=cy; j*=cx;
        for (;x<=j;x++) tyx[y][x]='-';
        }
    // v lines
    for (i=0;i<v.num;i+=3)
        {
        x=(v[i+0]-x0)/gx;
        y=(v[i+1]-y0)/gy;
        j=(v[i+2]   )/gy; j+=y;
        x*=cx; y*=cy; j*=cy;
        for (;y<=j;y++)
         if (tyx[y][x]=='-') tyx[y][x]='+';
          else               tyx[y][x]='|';
        }
    // convert char[ny][nx] to AnsiString
    for (txt="",y=0;y<ny;y++,txt+=eol)
     for (x=0;x<nx;x++) txt+=tyx[y][x];
    txt_xs=nx;  // just remember the text size for window resize
    txt_ys=ny;
    delete[] text;
    delete[] tyx;
    // [debug draw]
    // grid
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=TColor(0x000000FF);
    for (i=1,x=x0;i;x+=gx)
        {
        if (x>=x1){ x=x1; i=0; }
        bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y0);
        bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y1);
        }
    for (i=1,y=y0;i;y+=gy)
        {
        if (y>=y1){ y=y1; i=0; }
        bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x0,y);
        bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x1,y);
        }
    if (debug) bmp->SaveToFile("out1_grid.bmp");
    // h,v lines
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=TColor(0x00FF0000);
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Width=2;
    for (i=0;i<h.num;)
        {
        x=h[i]; i++;
        y=h[i]; i++;
        j=h[i]; i++;
        bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
        bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x+j,y);
        }
    for (i=0;i<v.num;)
        {
        x=v[i]; i++;
        y=v[i]; i++;
        j=v[i]; i++;
        bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
        bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y+j);
        }
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Width=1;
    if (debug) bmp->SaveToFile("out2_maze.bmp");

    delete[] pyx;
    return txt;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void update()
    {
    int x0,x1,y0,y1,i,l;
    x0=bmp->Width;
    y0=bmp->Height;
    // Font size
    Form1->mm_txt->Font->Size=Form1->cb_font->ItemIndex+4;
    txt_xf=abs(Form1->mm_txt->Font->Size);
    // mode
    Form1->mm_txt->Text=bmp2lintxt(bmp);
    // output
    Form1->mm_txt->Lines->SaveToFile("pic.txt");
    x1=txt_xs*txt_xf;
    y1=txt_ys*abs(Form1->mm_txt->Font->Height);
    if (y0<y1) y0=y1;
    x0+=x1+16+Form1->flb_pic->Width;
    y0+=Form1->pan_top->Height;
    if (x0<340) x0=340;
    if (y0<128) y0=128;
    Form1->ClientWidth=x0;
    Form1->ClientHeight=y0;
    Form1->Caption=AnsiString().sprintf("Picture -> Text ( Font %ix%i )",abs(Form1->mm_txt->Font->Size),abs(Form1->mm_txt->Font->Height));
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void draw()
    {
    Form1->ptb_gfx->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void load(AnsiString name)
    {
    if (name=="") return;
    AnsiString ext=ExtractFileExt(name).LowerCase();
    if (ext==".bmp")
        {
        bmp->LoadFromFile(name);
        }
    if (ext==".jpg")
        {
        TJPEGImage *jpg=new TJPEGImage;
        jpg->LoadFromFile(name);
        bmp->Assign(jpg);
        delete jpg;
        }
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    Form1->ptb_gfx->Width=bmp->Width;
    Form1->ClientHeight=bmp->Height;
    Form1->ClientWidth=(bmp->Width<<1)+32;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::flb_picChange(TObject *Sender)
    {
    load(flb_pic->FileName);
    update();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormActivate(TObject *Sender)
    {
    flb_pic->SetFocus();
    flb_pic->Update();
    if (flb_pic->ItemIndex==-1)
     if (flb_pic->Items->Count>0)
        {
        flb_pic->ItemIndex=0;
        flb_picChange(this);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just ignore the VCL stuff and convert the resulting text into whatever you have at disposal. I also use mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

So use whatever list you got or recode or use `std::vector` instead...

I edited out the texts from your image:

[image: input]

And this is the result using that as input:

```
+-----------+------------------     |
|           |                       |
|           |                       |
|     |     |     |     +-----------+
|     |           |     |           |
|     |           |     |           |
|     +-----------+     +-----+     |
|                 |           |     |
|                 |           |     |
+------     |     +-----+     |     |
|           |           |           |
|           |           |           |
|     ------+-----------+------     |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|     ------------------------------+
```

And here the saved debug bitmaps (from left to right: BW,Grid,Maze):

[image: BW] [image: Grid] [image: Maze]

The only important stuff from the code is function:

```
AnsiString bmp2lintxt(Graphics::TBitmap *bmp);
```

Which returns text from VCL (GDI based) bitmap.

Comment: Hi, thanks .... I think the hardest challenge here was to simplify the scanned image in a way to be pure black or white pixels. I was somewhere in the middle of that. Anyway, why are you used VCL? For the image manipulation only?

Comment: @Maverick VCL is the core of Delphi and C++ builder (Borland/Embarcadero IDEs). The stuff I used from it is: bitmap, GDI based rendering , AnsiString and file access from it ... So you can ignore the rendering, port the file and bitmap access ... And AnsiString is used just for the output (internaly is char* used so you canignore that too)

Comment: @Maverick In order to understand the VCL bitmap and renderig see [Display an array of color in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214) bullets GDI and GDI Bitmap. Also I did not test the stuff extensively so there might be hidden bugs ... For example I did not handle the case when the maze is borderless and aligned to bigger size than image resolution (that would most likely lead to access violation or segmentation fault) ...

Comment: Thanks don't bother with this, I have a gdi+ experience, so  I will convert it quite  easily.

Comment: @Maverick 6x3 cells looks best on monospaced fonts I use ... have updated code and output... Also see [How to speed up A* algorithm at large spatial scales?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23779490/2521214)

Comment: Excellent. As soon as I come back to home, I will give it a try.